# Halide: releases roadmap

Tags: halide

for clang there is a clear roadmap and we know when is the next release.
Where can I find Halide release roadmap?

I wonder when Halide 17 will be released, as we support clang 17 and we need the corresponded Halide version.

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder when Halide 17 will be released, as we support clang 17 and we need the corresponded Halide version.

Speaking as a maintainer of the Halide language, Halide releases usually trail LLVM/clang releases by a few weeks.

> for clang there is a clear roadmap and we know when is the next release. Where can I find Halide release roadmap?

As a small project, we don't have a published short-term roadmap.